# How do I Convert an Integer8 Value to DateTime?

Tags: .net, active-directory

How do a convert an Integer8 type value to a DateTime one? In particular, I'm attempting to get the *accountExpires* Active Directory User property in a human-readable form. `SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("accountExpires")` returns a value of "9223372036854775807."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DateTime.FromFileTime.

http://forums.asp.net/t/999913.aspx/1?Reading+AccountExpires+Property

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/19/96138.aspx

> An "Integer8" in AD is an object holding two 32 bit properties, called
>   LowPart and HighPArt. Such a property is returned as an generic RCW
>   (__ComObject), what you need to do is unwrap the underlying object or
>   just cast it to a LargInteger COM type. After that you have to combine
>   both properties into a long (64 Bit), if the value represents a date
>   you have to translate the format from FileTime to DateTime.
>
> Following shows how to retrieve "lastLogon" date property. !!! Set a
>   reference to the activeds.tlb, or create an interop library using
>   tlbimp.exe !!!!

```
     // Use a cast ...
     li = pcoll["lastLogon"].Value as LargeInteger;
     // Or use CreateWrapperOfType
     // li = (LargeIntegerClass)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(pcoll["lastLogon"].Value,
 typeof(LargeIntegerClass));
     // Convert to a long
     long date = (((long)(li.HighPart) << 32) + (long) li.LowPart);
     // convert date from FileTime format to DateTime
     string dt = DateTime.FromFileTime(date).ToString();
```