# Convert DateTime value to Integer8 for ActiveDirectory query

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create an ldap query to search Active Directory and filter the results to only return users that have a lastLogonTimestamp field with a value older than 30 days.

The ldap filter that I'm looking for is something like this:

```
"(&(ObjectClass=User)(lastLogonTimestamp<=" + lastLogonTimeStampLimit + "))"
```

My problem is that I have not been able to find any way to convert a .net DateTime value to the correct format for the lastLogonTimestamp field within Active Directory, which I've read is a 'Integer8' data type.

If it helps any, I've found a conversion to go the other way:

```
DateTime.FromFileTime((long)(user.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"][0]))
```

Comment: Here is a link with the answer to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169749/how-do-i-convert-an-integer8-value-to-datetime the accepted answer on this page will do the trick

Comment: If only there were a [`ToFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx) method...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I should have spotted that really.  I must be becoming over-reliant on Google to provide the answer!

Comment: If you care to put your comments as an answer, I'll tick it and get you the points.

Answer (score 1):

This code works to convert the AD object to a valid DateTime.  You can use it for any of the date values in AD (this example is for lastLogon).  The key seems to be the ActiveDs library.  The `long` cast doesn't seem to work, but `IADsLargeInteger` does just fine!

Here is a code sample including everything you need to convert from the AD type to a DateTime:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using ActiveDs; // Namespace added via ref to C:\Windows\System32\activeds.tlb

private DateTime? getLastLogin(DirectoryEntry de)
{
    Int64 lastLogonThisServer = new Int64();

    if (de.Properties.Contains("lastLogon"))
    {
        if (de.Properties["lastLogon"].Value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                IADsLargeInteger lgInt =
                (IADsLargeInteger) de.Properties["lastLogon"].Value;
                lastLogonThisServer = ((long)lgInt.HighPart << 32) + lgInt.LowPart;

                return DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogonThisServer);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```